# CakePHP 3 Validate Existing Entity from Database

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I have a multi-step step form that validates each portion of the form when it is submitted.  Suppose an user is going through the steps and then just chooses not to complete the form.  When the entity is retrieved on the admin side, for example, how can I validate it at the time I'm creating the entity from the database?  I already have my Validator for such a case that includes all my fields.  There are plenty of examples in the documentation for validating at save, but I'm not seeing or understanding how to do a validation when there is no save.  In Cake 2 we had the `validates()` method, how would it be done in Cake 3?

EDIT

Apologies for not being clear.  I have a standard view method such as this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $foo = $this->Foos->get($id);
    $this->set('foo', $foo);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['foo']);
}
```

All I want to do is simply validate `$foo` against one of my validators defined in `TableFoosTable.php`  Under normal circumstances this would not be an issue because a record would not get saved unless it was valid.  But in my case I have a multi-step form that is saving a portion of the record at a time.  The record could be in a state of not being fully valid because fields are missing.  When I retrieve it in my view method I would like to do something like `$this->Foos->validate()` which would tell me if the record is valid.  I would use my Validator that validates the entire record.

Please let me know if there is anymore information I can provide or how I could achieve this.

Comment: Your usage of the term "entity" is kinda ambiguous, and I really don't get how the database is involed here. Anyways, how to validate data is explained in the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-data** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-entities**

Comment: I have clarified my question.  Please let me know if more information would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution.

In my Controller:

```
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

public function view($id = null) {
    .
    .
    .
    $validator = new Validator();
    $validator = $this->Foos->valiationAllSteps($validator); // My validator that combines all steps
    $validator->errors($foo->toArray()); // Contains an error of errors, perform logic based on this.
}
```

Partial solution because it is not validating a `belongsToMany` relationship I have in my data even though that exists in my `Validator` and works in my `edit` method.

EDIT: This is solved.  I was missing a `requirePresence` in my validator.  With that in place, I'm able to validate in the controller without a save.